# how to configure Jira Dashboard in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, jira, logstash, kibana

I want to create a simple dashboard in kibana to show how many jira issues(priority wise) are opened and closed.

I have elasticsearch 2.2, logstsash and kibana (ELK) already integrated and running but, since i am very new to ELK i am not sure how i can have my jira instance to connect to logstash.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Elasticsearch <= 1.5, there is a Logstash [JIRA River Plugin](https://github.com/searchisko/elasticsearch-river-jira).

For > 1.5, there isn't anything that can read from the JIRA REST API, so pulling the data from JIRA into Elasticsearch would have to rely on something like the Logstash [JDBC input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html). If you're familiar with JIRA internals, this could definitely work for you - if not, then "here be dragons" as JIRA does some pretty sophisticated (some would call it scary) stuff with RDMS data storage. Specifically this is true of JIRA custom fields.

I know you weren't asking about this, but in the interest of completeness, [writing to JIRA](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/master/plugins-outputs-jira.html) (creating issues) is supported in pretty much all versions of Elasticsearch.